# ng-model gives null for extension less files in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I want to upload extension less file with the below snippet.

```
<button id="profileImage" ngf-select ng-model="imageFile" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-change="clearImageErrorMsgs()">Change Photo</button>
```

After i clicked on this "Change Photo" and select an extension less photo am getting "$scope.imageFile" is null. How can i resolve it in AngularJS v1.2.16 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload an extension-less file by setting **ngf-pattern** to a wildcard (asterisk *)

```
<button id="profileImage" ngf-select ng-model="imageFile" 
     ngf-pattern="'*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" 
     ngf-change="clearImageErrorMsgs()">Change Photo</button>
```

The pattern you were giving was failing a regexp text because it expected a dot (.).

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6S15Xnkmr8HLCNQJwWXD?p=preview) that demonstrates the use case, however of course the Submit fails with a 400 since I don't have anywhere to upload a file ;)

**Edit**
Given equivalent files "anon.jpg" and "anon" selecting "anon.jpg" yields *scope.file* as

```
$ngfName: "anon.jpg"
size:9612
type:"image/jpeg"
__proto__: Blob
```

Compare with the extension-less "anon" file:

```
lastModified:1453925356897
lastModifiedDate:Wed Jan 27 2016 15:09:16 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
name:"anon"
size:31002
type:""
webkitRelativePath:""
__proto__: File
```

Please note the difference in the **__proto__** properties.  Clearly ng-file-upload is treating extension-less (i.e. type-less) files differently.

All you need to do in your HTML to display the file name selected is something like this where scope.file is the ng-model:

```
<span>{{file.$ngfName || file.name}}</span>
```

I [updated the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/6S15Xnkmr8HLCNQJwWXD) to demonstrate this, have a look at the code.

Poking around in the debugger is a time saver.

If you're not satisfied, you need to file an issue [at the github project](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues).

Comment: Hi @ramblin, In my use case am able to select extension less image but after selecting the image, am getting $scope.imageFile is null in controller.

Comment: @Sandy have a look at the edit and updated plunkr, it should make clear the situation.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to omit the ngf-accept attribute?

Comment: Questions should land in the comment section rather than being posed as an answer.